# How to import Mongodb ObjectId from CSV file using mongoimport?

Tags: mongodb

I am struggling to import Mongodb's ObjectId from a CSV file using mongoimport:

I tried every combination and escape method I could think of but can't import ObjectId correctly from CSV.

First I tried importing exactly what I get exported from MongoDB to CSV. 
I am using MongoDB 2.2.1.

I just created two collections and referenced one document's _id in another document:

```
use yourdb
db.createCollection("student")
db.createCollection("class")
db.student.insert({"name":"Peter"})
db.student.find() returns { "_id" : ObjectId("5143af326d44e1ceb372121d"), "name" : "Peter" }
db.class.insert({"student_id": ObjectId("5143af326d44e1ceb372121d"),"name":"II-4"})
```

Then I used mongoexport command in shell:

```
mongoexport -h localhost:3002 -d yourdb -c classes --csv -f student_id,name > export.txt
```

Resulting CSV looks like this:

```
student_id,name
ObjectID(5143af326d44e1ceb372121d),"II-4"
```

Then I imported the resulting CSV using:

```
mongoimport -h localhost:3002 -d yourdb -c class --type csv --file export.txt --headerline
```

Quering class collection now returns:

```
db.class.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5143afc66d44e1ceb372121e"), "student_id" :   ObjectId("5143af326d44e1ceb372121d"), "name" : "II-4" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5143b44788df173ba096550e"), "student_id" : "ObjectID(5143af326d44e1ceb372121d)", "name" : "II-4" }
```

As you can notice student_id field in the second document is actually a string and not MongoDB ObjectId.

I am wrong on something or Mongo can't import it's own exported CSV??

Comment: What are you expecting to happen and what's happening instead?  You're importing back into the same collection in your example which makes it unclear.

Comment: I am trying to import MongoDB's ObjectID from csv and I am getting only strings imported in MongoDB. I have tried importing MongoDB's csv export but that didn't resulted in ObjectIDs. Seems like no one tried to import ObjectID field from a CSV file using mongoimport?

Comment: It worked fine when I tried this.  Does your actual test.csv file have a header line containing field names?  Your example CSV doesn't show it.

Comment: So you have successfully imported ObjectID - that's great! Yes - my CSV file contains headers. Did you imported CSV exported by MongoDB? I will update my question with exact example.

Comment: I could have sworn it worked before, but now that I try it again I'm seeing the same as you where the ObjectID becomes a string.

Comment: Thanks @JohnyHK - I now added the steps to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be reproduced in MongoDB 2.4.1.

The documentation (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongoimport/) states (emphasis by me):

> Note Do not use mongoimport and mongoexport for full instance,
>   production backups because they **will not reliably capture data type
>   information**. Use mongodump and mongorestore as described in “Backup
>   Strategies for MongoDB Systems” for this kind of functionality.

In this discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/RcnumM5QyxM a similar question was answered as this:

> Mongoimport with tsv or csv can **only import strings and numbers**, and 
>   not any of the other types specified in [1]. If you do want to import 
>   those types, and if you can produce JSON instead of TSV for your 
>   import file, that would be a good way to go; otherwise, you can write 
>   a post-processing step which converts the strings to the appropriate 
>   MongoDB types (based on some knowledge of what the type of value for a
>   given field should be).
>
> - Dan
>
> [1] http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Mongo+Extended+JSON

Comment: So it's not possible in the end they way I thought it was. Thanks for the explanation Ronasta.

Comment: Instructions on how to convert your CSV file to compatible JSON in order to preserve types: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21298840/943833

Answer (score 72):

For anyone with this issue who's trying to insert ObjectIds from JSON - it very much IS possible with a bit of modification to the existing data.

Replace:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5143afc66d44e1ceb372121e"),
  "student_id" : ObjectId("5143af326d44e1ceb372121d"),
  "name" : "II-4" }
```

With:

```
{ "_id" : {"$oid":"5143afc66d44e1ceb372121e"},
  "student_id" : {"$oid":"5143af326d44e1ceb372121d"},
  "name" : "II-4" }
```

Just use a regular expression to replace the ObjectId wrap.

Comment: Best answer! Should be green!

Comment: Yes, should be green!